# (Scala) initialize val by looping a list of strings

Tags: scala, loops

I'm having trouble looping threw my list of strings. I have a list of strings and i want to iterate threw each elements i'th char: first iteration would be 0 so i would take each strings first element and add them all together, then goes 1, 2 and so on. Basically output goes verticaly from top to bottom.

For example i have a list of strings like this:

```
"ABC
 DEF
 GHI"
```

So my out put would be:

```
"ADG
 BEH
 CFI"
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

In C# or C++ i could simply make two for loops and take myList[y][x] - how do i do this in scala without using muttable variables?
I come from C# and C++ background - i could do this blindfolded but scala - im so frustrated, i cannot find any good tutorials online i feel like its a desert out there(Or Maybe ironically enough the one blind here:))

-Thank you! ^^

Comment: Should the last row in the result be `CFI`?

Comment: @Brian We have computers to answer that question.

Comment: Darn! Even when i ask for help i make mistakes! :D Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 7):

The `transpose` method on collections does what you are trying to achieve.

```
List("ABC", "DEF", "GHI").transpose.map(xs => xs.mkString)
s: List[String] = List(ADG, BEH, CFI)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Range for the index:

```
val result = <yourlist>.headOption.map { head =>
    (0 until head.length).map { i =>
        <yourlist>.map(_(i))
    }
}
```

This would result in `Some(Vector(List(A, D, G), List(B, E, H), List(C, F, I)))`

Comment: Thank you so much!